# Disable background buttons when ionic popup is shown

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, popup

Hi one of my button (toggle) in the background is not disabled when a popup is shown. I can still click on it. How to handle that with ionic?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's with:

```
.popup-open {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To correct this, add:

```
.popup-container {
pointer-events: auto;}
```